# APN notification is not working but responce from api is success

Tags: react-native, expo, apn

I am implemented APN (apple push notification) it is getting success. I am getting result

> Blockquote
> [1] => Pushok\Response Object
> (
> [apnsId:Pushok\Response:private] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> [deviceToken:Pushok\Response:private] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> [statusCode:Pushok\Response:private] => 200
> [errorReason:Pushok\Response:private] =>
> [error410Timestamp:Pushok\Response:private] =>
> )

but in the app, I am not able to receive any notifications in the app. The app is built in expo react native. I am using an expo-notification package and using the getDevicePushTokenAsync() function.